# I have a dual boot on same disk partition, every file goes into 'windows.old' folder

Tags: windows-11, file-recovery, windows.old

I need to recover all my files and Operating System from windows.old (including Users, Program Files, Program Files (x86) Windows & ProgramData).

Please help.

[image]

Comment: what is preventing you from reading the files?

Comment: Have you tried simply copying the files over?

Comment: @Peregrino69 copy and paste? can i paste all file without error

Comment: OK. If you look at your question, you'll notice there's one thing missing - you forgot to ask one :-) You just described your situation and asked for help but don't specify what help exactly you need. So could you please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1768961/edit) your question to clarify this? ["How do I ask good question"](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) has advice on formulating a clear question that can be answered.